# facebook like button and Dreamweaver MX

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, dreamweaver

Hi I have googled this problem and checked the answers in this forum but to no avail.  I am using Dreamweaver MX to build my site.  I have put the code for Facebook like button into my code as instructed (using the IFrame code) and I am seeing nothing on my page.  Please advise

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my .NET site & here is code for facebook like button without using an iFrame:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like></fb:like>
```